# How do I append a function in a list on Python?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm using pyautogui in an application for repeating inputs. Here the user give a place and a hotkey to the script to make, all this functions should enter in the queue but instead they execute. Sorry for bad english

```
while (escolha!='5'):
    escolha = input('')
    if (escolha=='1'):
        print('Comecara uma contagem em sua tela, quando acabar deixe seu mouse em cima da area que sera clicada')
        time.sleep(5)
        print('5')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('4')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('3')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('2')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('1')
        localclick=pyautogui.position()
        print(localclick) 
        def clique():
            pyautogui.click(localclick)
            lista.append(clique())
   
    if (escolha=='2'):
        print("Digite sua hotkey separando por +. Exemplo: alt+tab+ [Limite de 3 teclas]")
        my_var = input("")
        my_var = my_var.split('+')
        def hotchave():
            pyautogui.hotkey(str(my_var[0]),str(my_var[1]),str(my_var[2]))
        lista.append(hotchave())
```

Comment: If you want to append the function to the list, don't call it - drop the `()` behind the function you want to append.

Answer (score 2):

Append it without `()`. That means call it.

Answer (score 0):

To reference a function, call it's name without the parentheses. To call it, use parentheses.

Reference:  `lista.append(hotchave)`
Call:   `lista.append(hotchave())`